# Row Level Security in Bigquery

Tags: security, google-bigquery, row-level-security

I am trying to create row level security policy in Bigqeuery

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY policy_name
ON `sample_project.sample_dataset.sample_table`
GRANT TO ('allAuthenticatedUsers')
FILTER USING (sample_column = 'abc');
```

Whenever I try to query the table, it will always return the data which matches with column value `abc`
But I need to create RLS policy so that it accepts a variable in `FILTER USING` and before executing any query, I will set that variable to any value.

I have used below query to create RLS

```
DECLARE variable STRING DEFAULT 'abc';
CREATE OR REPLACE ROW ACCESS POLICY policy_name
ON `sample_project.sample_dataset.sample_table`
GRANT TO ('allAuthenticatedUsers')
FILTER USING (sample_column = FORMAT('%t', variable));
```

But I got the below error while creating the policy
`Parameters and variables in FILTER USING expression are not supported`

Can someone please help me with this?